# How to switch to another screen by clicking on a custom image that is inside a table cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I don't have enough skills in iOS development that's why I need your help. Could you please to describe me how can i switch to another screen by clicking on a custom image that is inside a table cell? I am building an application based on **MVC architecture**, all my part of codes are divided to different files. I have a table which contains a certain number of cells. Each cell has a View and inside its content. One of the contents is a small picture when it clicked it should move to another screen. How can I realize it? I am so sorry I can't share you the parts of codes. Cause it is commercial project. I want to know the implementation principles in this case. I don't use (No - Storyboard), making an app only **programmatically**. I would be very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: you can add tap gesture on that image or you can use didselect there are many methods available on SO just find that suits your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways of handling it

1. Custom Cell:

- Custom Cell will have the action handler
- Delegates the call to Table View Controller with meta data
- Present another screen from Table View Controller

2. Table View Delegate Method

- `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`
- Based on the index check we can read the data from the datasource
- Present new screen from the table view controller

Comment: Oh okay thanks. But, I have a goal to go to another screen when clicking on a certain button contained in a cell. I do not need it to go to another screen when clicking on any part of the cell

Comment: @Alisher In that case you need to handle it in Custom Cell, this custom cell should delegate the call to table view controller and only a view controller can present or push another view controller not the cell.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    var body: some View {
        Link("Show example", destination: URL(string: "https://www.example.com")!) // 1 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank u for your comment. Actually, I making an app using UIKit framework not SwiftUI.